# How can you control visibility of datasource in Cesiumjs?

Tags: kml, cesiumjs

I want to display multiple datasources in a cesiumjs viewer but need to allow the user to select which ones they want to see at any given time. For example, if I load a kml and a czml file, how do I hide one and show the other? I can't find the cesiumjs way to do this with its API.

Answer (score 7):

*Update Feb 2016:* A `show` flag [has been proposed](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/3528) and may be added to a future version of Cesium.

*Original answer:*

Currently there is no `show` flag on the dataSource, however it is easy to add and remove the dataSource from the list of available dataSources, and this is used to get the show/hide functionality.

Here's a working demo:  Load the [Cesium Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases) Hello World example, and paste the following code into the left side, then hit Run (F8).  It should display a checkbox in the upper-left with show/hide functionality.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

// Create a typical CzmlDataSource.
var dataSource1 = new Cesium.CzmlDataSource();
dataSource1.load('../../SampleData/simple.czml');

// Add a checkbox at the top.
document.getElementById('toolbar').innerHTML =
    '<label><input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox" /> Show CZML</label>';

var checkbox = document.getElementById('showCheckbox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Checkbox state changed.
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        // Show if not shown.
        if (!viewer.dataSources.contains(dataSource1)) {
            viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource1);
        }
    } else {
        // Hide if currently shown.
        if (viewer.dataSources.contains(dataSource1)) {
            viewer.dataSources.remove(dataSource1);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

This code could be improved, for example it could be a "lazy load" where the `dataSource.load` does not get called until the first time it's shown.  Also if a dataSource has been hidden a while, you have to consider at what point should you be saving memory by destroying the dataSource rather than continuing to hold onto it (triggering a new lazy load if it is later shown again).

Answer (score 2):

as of now, show is a property of the data source, you can control it by accessing the property in dot or bracket notation:

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CzmlDataSource.html#show

```
const src = new Cesium.CzmlDataSource();
src.show = false;
```